# Mongo sum spring data in an array with criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Any tips how to calculate the sum of a field in array in a collection. 
My data structure is like this:

```
Employee {
id : "20"
salaries : [
{amount: 150},
{amount: 30},
{amount: 60}
]
}
```

I used mongo aggregation to deal with it and here is my code :

```
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(new Criteria("id").is("20")),Aggregation.group().sum("$salaries.amount").as("value"));
```

And this doesn't return any value.

Comment: did you solve this?